# How to decline a pull request on Bitbucket from Python?

Tags: python, api, bitbucket

How do you use Bitbucket's 2.0 API to decline a pull request via Python?

According to [their documentaion](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D/decline), it should be something like:

```
import requests
kwargs = {
    'username': MY_BITBUCKET_ACCOUNT,
    'repo_slug': MY_BITBUCKET_REPO,
    'pull_request_id': pull_request_id
}
url = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests/{pull_request_id}/decline'.format(**kwargs)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD), headers=headers)
```

However, this fails with `response.text` simply saying "Bad Request".

This similar code works for me with their other API endpoints, so I'm not sure why the decline method is failing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to authenticate with Oath. I wrote a wrapper for making these requests. Here is a simple example that works. The only thing I couldn't figure out was how to add a reason it was declined. I ended up making a request before I declined the PR that added a comment on why it was declined.

```py
import os

from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session


class Bitbucket(object):

    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, workplace, repo_slug):
        self.workplace = workplace  # username or company username
        self.repo_slug = repo_slug
        self.token_url = 'https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token'
        self.api_url = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/'
        self.max_pages = 10
        self.client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
        self.oauth = OAuth2Session(client=self.client)
        self.oauth.fetch_token(
            token_url=self.token_url,
            client_id=client_id,
            client_secret=client_secret
        )

    def get_api_url(self, endpoint):
        return f'{self.api_url}repositories/{self.workplace}/{self.repo_slug}/{endpoint}'


bitbucket = Bitbucket(os.environ['BITBUCKET_KEY'], os.environ['BITBUCKET_SECRET'], workplace='foo', repo_slug='bar')
pr_id = 1234
resp = bitbucket.oauth.post(f"{bitbucket.get_api_url('pullrequests')}/{pr_id}/decline")
if resp.status_code == 200:
    print('Declined')
else:
    print('Someting went wrong.')
```

Comment: I reached out to their support and found out that you can send the response reason as a message.

Example:
bitbucket.oauth.post(f"{bitbucket.get_api_url('pullrequests')}/{pr_id}/decline", data={'message': "My reason for declining."})

Comment: i found the same solution while lookin at dev tool in browser when declined PR, full solution in PowerShell is in https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-you-specify-a-reason-when-you-are-declining-a-Pull/qaq-p/1099355#M99918,  as for security header: use $user = "someuser"; $password = "yyyyqwef"      #app pass bb-cloud-pass
$pair = "$($user):$($password)"
$credentialsCloud = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($pair))
$headersCloud     = @{"accept" = "application/json"; "authorization" = "Basic $credentialsCloud" }